# unsigned integer in C printing incorrectly

Tags: c, types, bitwise-operators, bit

With the following code I declare an unsigned int and assign it the value of 236.  I then take the 1's complement of it and assign that to a separate variable.  When printed with printf, I expect the 2nd variable to print as "19", but its printing as "4294967059".  Why?  Doesn't the ~ bitwise operator take the value of the first variable (base 2) and "flip" the bits (1's complement), resulting in "19" in base 10?  Ints on my machine are 32-bit, and I assume this has something to do with 2^32-1 (4294967295), but I haven't figured it out

```
unsigned a = 236; // binary of this 11101100 = 236 base 10
unsigned b = ~a; // 1's complement to 00010011 = 19 base 10
printf("a: %u b: %u",a,b); // prints 236 and 4294967059.  WHY?
```

Comment: hint: how big is an int?

Comment: C99 §6.5.3.3/4 "The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that type minus E." - Maybe try your sample with an `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: @WhozCraig  Thanks for the C99 quote. Explains it perfectly.

Comment: Unsigned int is a 32 bit number.In your program,u used only 8 bits to represent the unsigned int and forgot to add 26 zero's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary of `a` is `00000000 00000000 00000000 11101100` if unsigned int is 4 bytes long. `~a` is `11111111 11111111 11111111 00010011`, which is 4294967295.

You can use unsigned char to represent a single byte(most likely it's 8 bits).

```
unsigned char a = 236;
unsigned char b = ~a;  // b = 19
```

Answer (score 2):

"*Ints on my machine are 32-bit*"

When you say `int` on your machine is 32 bit why you just consider 8 bit ?

`236 => 00000000000000000000000011101100`

1's complement of which is

`11111111111111111111111100010011 => 4294967059`